# SQL Server report Performance - Top Queries by Total CPU Time - what's included

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm trying to assess load level on sql server 2008/2016 by insert query.

There are articles I found which discuss that, like:
http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/insert
which talks about execution time.

I'm not very proficient in sql server, e.g. don't know how to evaluate execution plans.

I know that are handy performance reports, like "Performance - Top Queries by Total CPU Time".

I've searched and not found definitions of those reports.

So question is - which server tasks does this report include in CPU time calculations of queries, i.e.

1. indexes recalculation?
2. maybe even executing of triggers?
3. something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These are MDW or Management Data Warehouse reports and in particular the Query Statistics History introduced in SQL Server 2008. If you are interested in collecting this data then enable and [Configure the Management Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-collection/configure-the-management-data-warehouse-sql-server-management-studio).

[What are these reports anyway](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/billramo/2010/10/24/what-are-all-these-reports-anyways-mdw-report-series-part-5/).

By default, only the **top 10 queries** will be included in the Top 10 Queries by CPU, however, you can emulate the query behind the report and tweak the desired outcome using a query similar to the one below as discussed in this [article](https://seniordba.wordpress.com/2015/07/26/top-10-cpu-consuming-queries-in-sql-server/).

```
SELECT TOP X
    qs.total_worker_time/(qs.execution_count*60000000) as [Minutes Avg CPU Time],    
    qs.execution_count as [Times Run],
    qs.min_worker_time/60000000 as [CPU Time in Mins],
    SUBSTRING(qt.text,qs.statement_start_offset/2,
    (case when qs.statement_end_offset = -1 then len(convert(nvarchar(max), qt.text)) * 2
     else qs.statement_end_offset end -qs.statement_start_offset)/2) as [Query Text],
    db_name(qt.dbid) as [Database],
    object_name(qt.objectid) as [Object Name]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs cross apply
     sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) as qt
ORDER BY [Minutes Avg CPU Time] DESC
```

Comment: add `.0` to make it float

Answer (score 0):

Index recalculations and trigger executions are not performed as part of a query.  Index updates are part of maintenance activity and trigger executions are part of Insert/Update/Delete activity.

Generally speaking, there are no "server tasks" included in the calculations for the Top Queries report.  A query execution plan is based on that query and the data statistics available at the start of the query compilation.  The plan generated is independent of maintenance or IUD activity taking place on the server.

It is possible that other activity make cause the actual duration to increase, but that additional time is not directly attributable to the query.  The query is just forced to wait while the other activity completes.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, it showed I need more help :-) . I now tried to look at reports with "Activity", like Top Sessions, but could not identify indexes or insert activities (just "MS Query" and "jTDS"). Is there a way to assess their load?

Comment: You might make more progress here if you describe the problem you're having.  Why are you wanting to see index/insert activities?

Comment: I need to assess how load on server changes as table with indexes where inserts are made grows in size. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified query which shows top CPU time consumers.
It is not average, it is summarized.
Also it is grouped by query_plan_hash so same query with different params will be in one group.

**Note 1:** if query running frequently (~1 time every second) then it's statistics will be flushed every hour.

**Note 2:** User name will exist if only query is running at the moment

**Note 3:** If you need to keep stats for long time, you will need to store it somewhere separately. Also adding grouping by date will help with reporting

```
SELECT TOP 10
 SUM(qs.total_worker_time)/(1000000) AS [CPU Time Seconds],    
 SUM(qs.execution_count) AS [Times Run],    
 qs.query_hash AS [Hash],
 MIN(creation_time) AS [Creation time],
 MIN(qt.text) AS [Query],
 MIN(USER_NAME(r.user_id)) AS [UserName]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs CROSS apply
 sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt   
 LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS r ON qs.query_hash = 
r.query_hash
GROUP BY qs.query_hash
ORDER BY [CPU Time Seconds] DESC
```